# ggplot2: Adjust the symbol size in legends

Tags: r, ggplot2

How should I change the size of symbols in legends? I checked the document of `theme` but found no answer.

Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2);library(grid)
set.seed(1000)
x <- 1:6
mu <- sin(x)
observed <- mu + rnorm(length(x), 0, 0.5*sd(mu))
data <- data.frame(
  t=rep(x, 2), 
  value=c(mu, observed) - min(mu, observed) + 0.5, 
  class = rep(c("mu", "observed"), each=length(x)))
mu <- data$value[1:length(x)]
observed <- data$value[1:length(x) + length(x)]
mu.min <- mu - 3 * 0.5 * sd(mu)
mu.max <- mu + 3 * 0.5 * sd(mu)
g <- ggplot(data=data)
g <- g + geom_point(aes(x=value, y=t, shape=class, size=24)) + scale_size(guide="none")
g <- g + scale_shape(name="", labels=expression(paste(S[u](t), ", the observation at time ", t), paste(mu[u](t), ", the mean of ", tilde(S)[u](t), "          ")))
stat_function.color <- gray(0.5)
g <- g + geom_segment(aes(y=1:6, yend=1:6, x=mu.min, xend=mu.max, linetype="2", alpha = 1), color=stat_function.color) + scale_alpha(guide="none") + scale_linetype(name= "", labels=expression(paste("probability density function (pdf) of ", tilde(S)[u], " at time ", t)))
for(i in 1:length(x)) {
  g <- g + stat_function(fun=function(x, i) {
    ifelse( x <= mu.max[i] & x >= mu.min[i], dnorm(x, mu[i], sd(mu)) + i, NA)
    }, color=stat_function.color, args=list(i=i))
}
background.color <- gray(0.75)
g <- g + theme(
  axis.text=element_blank(),
  title=element_text(size=rel(1.5)),
  legend.text=element_text(size=rel(1.5)),
  legend.position="top",
  legend.direction="vertical",
#   legend.key.size = unit(2, "cm"),
  panel.background=element_rect(fill=background.color), 
  panel.grid.major=element_line(color=background.color),
  panel.grid.minor=element_line(color=background.color)
  ) + coord_flip()
plot(g)
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356052/control-ggplot2-legend-look-without-affecting-the-plot

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can make these kinds of changes manually using the `override.aes` argument to `guide_legend()`:

```
g <- g + guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5)))
print(g)
```

Comment: @Ibo: are you sure? Your example code looks like it would work if you had a color scale in the legend, my example was for a shape scale, like in the original question. AFAIK this still works if you have a shape scale that you are modifying. At this point I would prefer Duc_Hokie's suggestion to use the theme options, however.

Answer (score 116):

You should use:

```
theme(legend.key.size = unit(3,"line"))
```

Comment: IMHO that is the more appropriate answer since it uses `theme` which was mentioned in the question.

Comment: This code increases the area around the symbol, not the symbol itself.  The guides code is more appropriate.

Comment: I couldn't make it work for small values, e.g. ``unit(0.1, "line")``

Comment: but this is the code that actually achieves what most of us probably came to this page looking to do...

Comment: This worked for me. Whereas, the accepted answer did not.

Comment: For some reason I can increase its size with `legend.key.size` but I can't find a way to decrease the squared figures' sizes smaller than default, using `theme()`

Comment: neither solution alone worked for me, but both together worked. reason: increasing guide size hides line type, so I also needed to increase the area around the symbol.

Comment: Note: In trying to reduce the size of the legend key, I discovered two things. 1) `legend.key.size` changes the X and Y dimensions of they key together. If you want a rectangle, not a square you need to use `legend.key.height` and `legend.key.width`.  2) if you set `legend.key.size` smaller than the font size, it appears to set the height to the font size and the width to whatever you set. @PatrickT if you want something smaller than 1 line, try `unit(1, "pt")` instead.

Answer (score 60):

Marius's answer did not work for me as of R version 3.2.2. You can still call `guide_legend()` with the same `override.aes` argument but you will need to specify `color` instead of `shape` in the wrapper function.

So if you're running a later version of R, try this instead:

```
g + guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5)))
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @Ibo in the comment, this may have been due to the color scale in the `ggplot` object. If the `ggplot` object contains a color scale, the mapping of size (`size=5`) has to be set on the color instead.

Comment: I think the reason it did not work for you was because you had a color scale in your plot and not a shape scale. Marius's answer changes the size of the shapes in a legend for shape. Your line of code changes the size of shape of the legend for a color scale

Answer (score 13):

If you want to change the sizes of 2 components of a legend independently, it gets trickier, but it can be done by manually editing the individual components of the plot using the `grid` package.

Example based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34304453/3174566):

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(n = 100),
                  x2 = factor(rep(c('first', 'second'), each = 50)))
set.seed(1)
dat$y = 5 + 1.8 * as.numeric(dat$x2) + .3 * dat$x + rnorm(100)

# basic plot
g <- ggplot(data = dat,
       aes(x = x, y = y, color = x2))+
   theme_bw()+
   geom_point()+
   geom_smooth(method = 'lm')
```

[image]

```
# make the size of the points & lines in the legend larger
g + guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 2)))
```

[image]

```
# Make JUST the legend points larger without changing the size of the legend lines:
# To get a list of the names of all the grobs in the ggplot
g
grid::grid.ls(grid::grid.force())

# Set the size of the point in the legend to 2 mm
grid::grid.gedit("key-[-0-9]-1-1", size = unit(4, "mm"))

# save the modified plot to an object
g2 <- grid::grid.grab()
ggsave(g2, filename = 'g2.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

As of 12/1/2022, in ggplot2 version 3.4.0, the argument:

```
guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5)))
```

no longer works....instead, replace `"size = 5"` with `"linewidth = 5"`

Comment: It's true, it does not work anymore and I was confused why running some old script led to smaller legend symbols. Many thanks.

Comment: size has been deprecated to linewidth in geom_line(). It still works in geom_line but wont generate desired result in legend argument as pointed out by Andrew. See https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/08/ggplot2-3-4-0-size-to-linewidth/