# Control ggplot2 legend look without affecting the plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I'm plotting lines with ggplot2 like this:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width,Petal.Length,color=Species)) + geom_line() + theme_bw()
```

[image: current plot].

I find legend marks to be small so I want them to be bigger. If I change the size, lines on the plot change too:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width,Petal.Length,color=Species)) + geom_line(size=4) + theme_bw()
```

[image: thick plot lines].

But I only want to see thick lines in the legend, I want lines on the plot to be thin. I tried to use `legend.key.size` but it changes the square of the mark, not the width of the line:

```
library(grid)  # for unit
ggplot(iris,aes(Petal.Width,Petal.Length,color=Species))+geom_line()+theme_bw() + theme(legend.key.size=unit(1,"cm"))
```

[image: big legend keys]

I also tried to use points:

```
ggplot(iris,aes(Petal.Width,Petal.Length,color=Species)) + geom_line() + geom_point(size=4) + theme_bw()
```

But of course it still affects both plot and legend:

[image: points]

I wanted to use lines for the plot and dots/points for the legend.

So I'm asking about two things:

1. How to change width of line in the legend without changing the plot?
2. How to draw lines in the plot, but draw points/dots/squares in the legend?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

To change line width only in the legend you should use function `guides()` and then for `colour=` use `guide_legend()` with `override.aes=` and set `size=`. This will override size used in plot and will use new size value just for legend.

```
ggplot(iris,aes(Petal.Width,Petal.Length,color=Species))+geom_line()+theme_bw()+
       guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3)))
```

[image]

To get points in legend and lines in plot workaround would be add `geom_point(size=0)` to ensure that points are invisible and then in `guides()` set `linetype=0` to remove lines and `size=3` to get larger points.

```
ggplot(iris,aes(Petal.Width,Petal.Length,color=Species))+geom_line()+theme_bw()+
       geom_point(size=0)+
       guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3,linetype=0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Since ggplot v3.4.0, `size` argument has to be replaced by `linewidth`, so with version ggplot >= 3.4.0 it would be : ```r
ggplot(iris,aes(Petal.Width,Petal.Length,color=Species)) + geom_line() + theme_bw() + geom_point(size=0) + guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes=list(linewith=3,linetype=0)))
```