# making legend colors more visible in geom_line in ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

How do I make the legend category colors bigger so that it is easy to identify what the colors correspond to in the graph.

Following is how I got the plot

```
 ggplot(data=dur)
 +geom_line(mapping=aes(x=yr,y=Country,color=dur$elec..sys,size=1.1))
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356052/control-ggplot2-legend-look-without-affecting-the-plot

Comment: Thanks. This worked 
  
  ggplot(data=dur)+geom_line(mapping=aes(x=yr,y=Country,color=dur$elec..sys,size=1.1))+guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3)))