# Customising legend size-symbol items in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm mapping size to a variable with something like a log distribution - mostly small values but a few very large ones.  How can I make the legend display custom values in the low-value range?  For example:

```
df = data.frame(x=rnorm(2000), y=rnorm(2000), v=abs(rnorm(2000)^5))
p = ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col=v, size=v), alpha=0.75) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 10)
print(p)
```

I've tried `p + guides(shape=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=8)))` solution posted in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059093/ggplot2-adjust-the-symbol-size-in-legends), but it makes no difference in my plot.  In any case I'd like to use specific legend size values e.g. v = c(10,25,50,100,250,500) instead of the default range e.g. c(100,200,300,400)..

Grateful for assistance.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get different break points of size in legend, modify `scale_size_area()` by adding argument `breaks=`. With `breaks=` you can set breakpoints at positions you need.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col=v, size=v), alpha=0.75) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 10,breaks=c(10,25,50,100,250,500))
```

Comment: Thanks Didzis for speedy response :)