# Assign same custom color to two lines coming from different data-frames but in the same plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following plot, plotting data coming from two different data-frames:

```
ggplot() + 
  stat_summary( data = d0_400, aes(x=number, y=(1-value), shape=as.factor(0), size=1 ) , fun.y=mean, geom="line" ) +
  stat_summary( data = d0_400, aes(x=number, y=(1-value), shape=as.factor(0), size=4 ) , fun.y=mean, geom="point" ) +
  stat_summary( data = d1_400, aes(x=number, y=(1-value), shape=as.factor(1), size=1 ) , fun.y=mean, geom="line" ) +
  stat_summary( data = d1_400, aes(x=number, y=(1-value), shape=as.factor(1), size=4 ) , fun.y=mean, geom="point" ) +
  scale_size(range = c(1,5), guide=FALSE) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(0,1) )
```

With this code I get the following plot:

[image]

I would like to get the following instead:

- A custom hexadecimal colour for the lines and the shapes
- Optional: Shapes appearing bigger in the shape legend, as they are too hard to distinguish in this size, and filling them with white colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the coloured lines, just add a `colour` argument

```
p = ggplot() + 
  stat_summary( data = d0_400, ..., geom="line", colour = "#hexnum" )
```

Also, a quick google of the optional question took me to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059093/ggplot2-adjust-the-symbol-size-in-legends):

The solution provided is

```
p = p + guides(shape=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=5)))
```

Comment: perfect! one more follow up, is it possible to fill the shapes with a certain colour. I tried `fill="#456987"` but did not work?

Comment: Bit of a hack, but you could just change the point character. Add the argument `pch = 16` which should be a filled circle. Then the `colour` will effect it.

Comment: which function should I pass `pch` as a parameter?

Comment: The `stat_summary` function. 
`stat_summary( data = d0_400, ..., geom="point", colour = "#AFE1EE", pch = 16 )`.
If this isn't sufficient you'll get a more comprehensive answer if you ask a new question

Comment: what a hack! will need to find a way to override the shape in the legend. the `pch` does not reflect to the shape legend: `scale_shape_manual(values=c(0,1)`