# ggplot2 scale_fill_gradient disappears inconsistently

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been learning how to build maps for work showing covid-19 infection data.  In addition to a national map, I am producing regional maps for the northeast, south, west, and midwest.  The code is identical, I just use different filterings on the national data frame.  I produce one map for each day of data and use gganimate to make frames and finally gifski to make an animated gif.  The basic code for the national map is:

```
p <- pop_counties_cov %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = infRate, geometry=geometry), color = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = states_sf, fill = NA, color = "black", size = 0.25) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA) +   
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "% Population Infected", trans = "log", low='green', high='red',
                      na.value = "white",
                      breaks=c(0, round(max(pop_counties_cov$infRate),3))) +
  geom_point(data=AFMCbases, aes(x=longitude.1, y=latitude.1,size=personnel), color = "hotpink") +
  #geom_label_repel(data=AFMCbases, aes(x=longitude.1, y=latitude.1, label=Base)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(size='AFMC \nMil + Civ') +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", 
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

As an example, the final frame it produces is

[image]

This code on the other hand:

```
p <- mw_pop_counties_cov %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = infRate, geometry=geometry), color = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = mw_states_sf, fill = NA, color = "black", size = 0.25) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA) +   
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "% Population Infected", trans = "log", low='green', high='red',
                      na.value = "white",
                      breaks=c(0, round(max(mw_pop_counties_cov$infRate),3))) +
  geom_point(data=mwBases, aes(x=longitude.1, y=latitude.1,size=personnel), color = "hotpink") +
  #geom_label_repel(data=AFMCbases, aes(x=longitude.1, y=latitude.1, label=Base)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(size='AFMC \nMil + Civ') +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", 
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

which is the same except that the data frames have been filtered down to only the midwest states, produces

[image]

Note the appearance of the color scale.

Is there some typo I'm not seeing because I've been staring at this too long?
My script produces 5 animations, 1 each for the national map, then the 4 census regions (northeast, midwest, south and west).  The color scale appears on the west and midwest maps, but not the other three.  This is despite the fact I basically just cut and pasted and then changed the dataframe names.

What am I doing wrong?  I WANT the color scale to appear on ALL maps.

Comment: Have you try to pass `show.legend = FALSE` in `geom_sf` ? Can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset ?

Comment: Hello @jerH, isn't it because of the proportions? I mean, you compare a country vs a region and you use a log transformation.

Comment: @dc37 I'm not exactly sure how to provide a reproducible example...the covid data I read from a URL, but the county population data is from a rather large .csv I only have locally. If there's a good way to do that please let me know.  Also, I'll edit the OP to make it clear that I WANT the color scale to appear..I don't know why it isn't in some cases.

Comment: I see. Sorry for the mis-understanding.

Comment: @Manu In each case, I'm color-coding each county by the percent of it's population that has tested positive, so the range is [0,1] regardless. But for the scale I use the max infection rate in the respective data frame. For example, in the midwest map it's `breaks=c(0, round(max(mw_pop_counties_cov$infRate),3)))` + so I take the max of the midwest counties rates, while in the national map it's `breaks=c(0, round(max(pop_counties_cov$infRate),3)))` so it's the max of all counties. The log transform is just cuz the data is very skewed...

Comment: This looks like a sizing issue to me - you have 4 pink dots on the first map, and only 3 on the second. Maybe that does not leave enough room for the color scale at the given pixel size? Try changing legend size - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059093/ggplot2-adjust-the-symbol-size-in-legends for how to do that.

Comment: @user12728748 you may be on to something...I changed to rounding to 2 decimal places instead of 3 and the scale re-appeared on some of the charts...remained missing on a couple though.  The weird thing though is that I used to not round at all and the scale appeared on all of them, just out to like 5 or 6 decimal places.  Would have though rounding down to 3 wouldn't have been an issue.  I'd actually like to format them as %'s (so the midwest map above would have a scale from 0 to 0.132% instead of just 0.132 but don't know how to do that either!

Comment: Do you need a log transform for the proportion infected?  And I wonder if you should make the maximum the same across all maps for better comparison.

Comment: @Edward you're probably right...personally I'm not a huge fan of this % infected map anyway, but somebody above me in the food chain wants it.  I'll give it a run without and see how it looks.  I actually want to wrap this up and move onto a) trying to project #cases forward and b) producing a version of this [this](https://i0.wp.com/kieranhealy.org/files/misc/cov_case_sm.png?w=456&ssl=1) map based around the locations highlighted by the pink dots...

Comment: I don't mean rounding of values, but the physical horizontal space on your map. If you changed the gradient name from `% Population Infected` to `% PI` just to try if that is the issue, you might fit the scale on the first plot as well.

Comment: @jerH u still struggling? If so, please make the code repdocucible - meaning link to the url where you found the data, and also the steps to filter to the different data frames. Include all packages loaded.  To make a reproducible example, best is to use the `reprex` package (and use RStudio). Install it and it will be fully integrated in RStudio. Mark all your code, click the 'addins' button and 'render reprex'

Comment: @Tjebo Thanks for the info on `reprex` I'll check it out.  Big issue for me was that I pretty much put the county population data together by hand because I had to manually fix a bunch of things to ensure consistency between the sources..like it's "City of New York" from one source and "New York City" in another.  As for the original problem, a simple fix turned out to be adding a newline character in the scale label.  Once I made it `scale_fill_gradient(name = "% Population \nInfected"...` it worked just fine

Comment: @Edward tried it without the log transform and you basically wind up with an almost solid green map...

Comment: would suggest to add this as answer, for future generations, because you received some upvotes, which shows that some people found the problem interesting - it may therefore help future researches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue does appear to be one of horizontal space on the output plot.  By simply changing the scale caption from

```
scale_fill_gradient(name = "% Population Infected",...
```

to

```
scale_fill_gradient(name = "% Population \nInfected",
```

Note the newline character `\n`

The output map now has the color scale I was looking for

[image]